# Does framing a website cause phishing alerts?

Tags: url-shorteners, phishing

I do not know if you guys ever heard of hope.ly? It is a url shortening service created by bitly and was trying to help Red Cross in order to get donations.

They simply show a frame upper side of the shortened urls.

[image]

Now I see they closed the website, google chrome and twitter gives phishing alerts no matter which hope.ly link I click. So, do you think framing websites like that could cause your domain labeled as spam above?

Comment: Good question. If the site was closed and domain redirected, wouldn't the hope.ly URLs die with it?

I would think it's because the referring URL's domain name is no longer active, would be the reason the alerts are coming up.

Comment: Google Chrome was giving phishing alerts before the site shut down.I do not think this issue is related with site close.

Comment: Interesting.... 

You may want to edit the part of your question that states "Now I see they closed the website, google chrome and twitter gives".. If this occurred before the site close, it would be irrelevant to the issue at hand right?

Comment: It's nice to donate but things like that hinder user experience. There's better ways of serving a donation program that is more effective and less of a hindering for people having to wait to get to the next page or even wait.

Answer (score 1):

"Framing" websites should not cause any harm.

Unless of course the site you are "Framing" has malware.

Then Google is picking up a malicious link on your website.

You could try running the links through malware checkers like:
https://www.virustotal.com/
http://sitecheck.sucuri.net/

It could also be affecting your ranking. Because if the site is not up then the links are dead.

Google crawls your site and says  WOAH look at all these dead links. That isn't very good!!

I'd suggest 
- check if they work
- if they do run them through sucuri and virustotal
- if they don't or come back infected remove and/or update them on your site.